# opencv - Simple 2D <-> 2D transform

Tags: python, opencv

What I want to do is to match a linear axis system (axis coordinates) with image pixels of a photo. First i want to calibrate a camera using a grid of circles using corresponding 2D axis coordinates (3D coordinate in z=0 plane). This is done once, the camera is steady. Later on I want to find contours in images and get their corresponding axis coordinates. In Python I used:

```
ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(gray, (16,8))
imgpoints.append(corners)
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

In objpoints I putted the corresponding coordinates. E.g.

```
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:16,0:8].T.reshape(-1,2)
objpoints.append(objp)
```

The code is more or less from this tutorial: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html

I know than I can use projectPoints to get a point in axis coordinate in image pixels. But I would like to do the oposite and get an axis coordinate from a image pixel. I read a lot here of stackoverflow regarding this topic, but I did not find a clear answer. From want I understood is that I have to undistort my picture and to use solvePnP to get the camera coordinates. I have to admit that I don't understand how to interpret these steps. I'm not sure which image should be undistorted (my circle grid for calibration or the image i process later) and how to combine it with solvePnP. Or is it even possible to just undistort the points of the contours without undistorting an complete image? I also don't know how to obtain the position as a image pixel from the result of solvePnP. Additionally I need to pass at least 4 points to solvePnP but what i want is to transform single points. Maybe I understand something wrong and I need to do something completly different.
I would appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry guys. Problem solved. I understood the whole concept wrong. I already got the camera pose out of the calibration routine. I calculated a ray hitting z=0 plane and now I got the correct 3D point. Before doing this I also used undistortpoints and it works perfectly. Maybe this could also help people having the same problem.